# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY Angular

Tags: angular, docker

I'm using the Angular2/Angular4 to build the application and I'm getting these errors when I'm running command "npm install".

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.2.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@4.2.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.2.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@4.2.3
```

Thing is, I'm gettings these modules in the `node_modules/...`, my app is working perfectly, but my problems are starting when I'm trying to use Docker:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/common@4.2.3 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/forms@4.2.3 wants @angular/common@4.2.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser@4.2.3 wants @angular/common@4.2.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.2.3 wants @angular/common@4.2.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@4.2.3 wants @angular/common@4.2.3
```

As you can see, I'm getting the errors almost on the same modules that I got during the "npm install". So, why commandline wants the same versions of the modules that already was installed and doesn't see them?

I tried to delete "node_nodules" folder and start the clean project, I saw the similar answers here, but they are not relevant or not helping.

Package.json

I used angular2-webpack-starter, when I started to receive these errors, I tried to update all modules to Angular4 but nothing changed.

```
{
  "name": "angular2-webpack-starter",
  "version": "5.4.1",
  "description": "An Angular 2 Webpack Starter kit featuring Angular 2 (Router, Http, Forms, Services, Tests, E2E, Coverage), Karma, Protractor, Jasmine, Istanbul, TypeScript, and Webpack by AngularClass",
  "keywords": [
    "angular2",
    "webpack",
    "typescript"
  ],
  "author": "Patrick Stapleton <patrick@angularclass.com>",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build:aot:prod": "npm run clean:dist && npm run clean:aot && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build:aot": "npm run build:aot:prod",
    "build:dev": "npm run clean:dist && webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "build:docker": "npm run build:prod && docker build -t angular2-webpack-start:latest .",
    "build:prod": "npm run clean:dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "ci:aot": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
    "ci:jit": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e",
    "ci:nobuild": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
    "ci:testall": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
    "ci:travis": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e:travis",
    "ci": "npm run ci:testall",
    "clean:dll": "npm run rimraf -- dll",
    "clean:aot": "npm run rimraf -- compiled",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist compiled dll",
    "docker": "docker",
    "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
    "e2e:live": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor:live",
    "e2e:travis": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor:delay",
    "e2e": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor",
    "github-deploy:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubDev",
    "github-deploy:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubProd",
    "github-deploy": "npm run github-deploy:dev",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "postinstall": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "protractor:delay": "sleep 3 && npm run protractor",
    "protractor:live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
    "server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --open --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist -c-1 --cors",
    "server:prod:ci": "http-server dist -p 3000 -c-1 --cors",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "test": "npm run lint && karma start",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
    "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
    "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "webpack": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular2-tag-input": "^1.2.3",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "^0.8.8",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.34",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "~2.53.39",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.0",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
    "@types/webpack": "^2.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "~3.0.0-beta.18",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~2.0.0-rc.3",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "find-root": "^1.0.0",
    "gh-pages": "^0.12.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.2",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng-router-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "ngc-webpack": "1.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.1",
    "optimize-js-plugin": "0.0.4",
    "parse5": "^3.0.1",
    "protractor": "^4.0.14",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "~2.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "string-replace-loader": "1.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "ts-node": "^2.0.0",
    "tslib": "^1.5.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.3",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "2.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.1",
    "webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "webpack-merge": "~3.0.0"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Comment: can you provide your `package.json`?

Comment: Just added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution - there was the trick with the version of the angular packages. After updating to the last version everything's fine.